# CSS will-change property for performance boost?

Tags: javascript, html, css, smooth-scrolling, locomotive-scroll

Can we use CSS' [will-change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change) property for the Performance boosts for inview translating section ?

Here **on scroll** when this section appears in viewport **[data-scroll-section-inview]** attribute added via javascript and removed when section disappears
can we apply will change property here
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change) says use it use sparingly not sure what's the best approach

```
//html-
<section
  data-scroll-section
  data-scroll-section-id="section1"
  data-scroll-section-inview
  style="
    transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -775, 0, 1);
    opacity: 1; pointer-events: all;">
                                    
</section>
```

```
// css
[data-scroll-section-inview] {
  will-change: transform, opacity;
}
```

I'm using virtual scroll using a library called [locomotive-scroll](https://locomotivemtl.github.io/locomotive-scroll/) currently page lags and after applying will-change didn't notice any performance boosts

Comment: Does the page lags currently without `will-change`?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Yes

Comment: So using it may help and it's fine. But maybe the problem is somewhere else

Comment: When [data-scroll-section-inview]  attribute is added will-change property applied and when the section not present in the viewport this attribute is removed so do we need to  reset the will-change property